# Maven build on AWS wrongly using SNAPSHOT private repo

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, jenkins, repository, pom.xml

We have a private maven repo (artifactory) and we have a release jar (cryptolib-0.9.7.jar) in the libs-release folder.

Building locally or on Jenkins (hosted on Azure), all works fine.  Building on codebuild on AWS, maven tries (and fails) to download from libs-snapshot instead.

Jenkins & local output (v3.3.9)...

```
Downloading: http://[our-repo]/artifactory/libs-release/org/openpseudonymiser/cryptolib/0.9.7/cryptolib-0.9.7.pom
Downloaded: http://[our-repo]/artifactory/libs-release/org/openpseudonymiser/cryptolib/0.9.7/cryptolib-0.9.7.pom (457 B at 3.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://[our-repo]/artifactory/libs-release/org/openpseudonymiser/cryptolib/0.9.7/cryptolib-0.9.7.jar
Downloaded: http://[our-repo]/artifactory/libs-release/org/openpseudonymiser/cryptolib/0.9.7/cryptolib-0.9.7.jar (13 KB at 234.8 KB/sec)
```

AWS/CodeBuild output (v.3.3.3)...

```
Downloading: http://[our-repo]/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/openpseudonymiser/cryptolib/0.9.7/cryptolib-0.9.7.jar
```

Both are executing `mvn -B install`.  I've tried all sorts of online suggestions and the the pom repository section currently looks like this (which now seems to ONLY attempt download from central)...

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>libs-snapshot</name>
        <url>http://[our-repo]/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>libs-release</name>
        <url>http://[our-repo]/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

What am I missing (apart from hair!!!)??

Comment: Doh!

"When you use Maven with an AWS CodeBuild provided Java build environment, Maven pulls build and plugin dependencies from the secure central Maven repository at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2. *This happens even if your build project's pom.xml file explicitly declares other locations to use instead.*"

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-maven-repos

Comment: posting the dependency part of the pom might help shed some light on this

Comment: add your findings as answer and accept them, this should help other folks who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! "When you use Maven with an AWS CodeBuild provided Java build environment, Maven pulls build and plugin dependencies from the secure central Maven repository at repo1.maven.org/maven2. This happens even if your build project's pom.xml file explicitly declares other locations to use instead." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-maven-repos

My solution was to delete the default settings.xml in the buildspec install phase.

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - rm /root/.m2/settings.xml
```